# What does the error "The function return type is not supported" mean in matlab's calllib?

Tags: matlab, dll, struct, shared-libraries, loadlibrary

Am using calllib to access an external DLL from matlab.  The DLL has a function in it, with a signature that looks like:

```
typedef struct resultStruct {
    double E;
    double W;
    double N; 
    double S;
    double Z;
    double Y;
} RESULT_STRUCT;


typedef struct inputStruct {
    double A;  
    double B; 
    double C; 
} INPUT_STRUCT;

RESULT_STRUCT calc(
    const INPUT_STRUCT* input);
```

When I try to invoke this in matlab,

```
loadlibrary('calc.dll','calc.h');
input.A = 1;
input.B = 2;
input.C = 3;

[res, st] = calllib('calc','calc',input);
```

I get the error:

```
??? Error using ==> calllib
The function return type is not supported.
```

Surprisingly, google shows up no hits on that error message, and there is nothing in the documentation for calllib: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/calllib.html

My guess, is that since the function is returning a structure, matlab is puking.  But there's nothing in the documentation to suggest that.  Although, none of the examples matlab provides, includes a structure as an output variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the same as you, namely that MATLAB doesn't like a struct return type. Try returning a simple type and see if that works. Then I suggest contacting the excellent MATLAB support people.

Comment: Confirmed from Mathworks.  Matlab doesn't like the struct return type.  Only int/double/float style return types are supported.

Comment: @John Good to hear. I use calllib myself to link MATLAB to a DLL that I develop - I'll take extra special care not to return anything fancy from the DLL!